# Why does my Cowboystudio NPT-04 not trigger flash with Live View on Canon T3i?

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers

I just purchased a Cowboystudio flash trigger, model NPT-04 to use on my Canon T3i with a Canon 430 EX ii Speedlite.

It seems to only work when looking through the viewfinder- if live view is on (using the LCD screen to aim and focus), then the flash trigger does not send a signal to the flash, and the flash does not fire.

Is this normal? With the flash mounted to the camera's hotshoe, it flashes regardless of if live view is on or off.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to help you and give you some advice.
First of all, the flash trigger has to work without the camera, so you may have done this test, but have you tried to click on the test button on the top with the 430exii mounted on the receiver? If you did, the flash didn't work?
I had the same problem and It was solved by change the trasmiter and the receiver batteries.

I had an similar [equipment](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/4-channel-wireless-flash-trigger-PT-04-2-receivers-T3E-free-shipping/382976151.html) of yours, but unfortunately I've had another problems, my 580exii stopped to work with it because the receiver didn't support the weight (wierd no?)
So at the end I realize that this wasn't a good equipment, and I decided to buy my [YN622c](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Yongnuo-YN-622C-Wireless-TTL-Flash-Trigger-1-8000s-Flash-Ratio-for-Canon-Camera/638714490.html)
It's an awesome flash trigger, which is a transiever (can be used with reciever and trasmiter as well), has 1/8000 speed sync (even with 1/1 power), 100 meters of limit distance, and the topest of the advantages: total control of your flash in your camera.
Believe me, it worth!

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar flash trigger, It's from YongNuo.
I think that it's not normal because this seems to be bad contact between the hotshoes and the trasmiter.
I had a similar problem, and I just clean the contact in the hotshoe and works. I don't know if will work but you can try.